# Ruby vs. Python: which one is easier to keep track of different language versions?

Tags: python, ruby

I've heard that there are issues with the more recent versions of Python (3.x?) that have led to slower adoption. Is that true? And if so, is it an issue when different people are using different versions of the language? Which version of Python is most widespread?

Does Ruby have a similar issue, or did most people switch to 1.9?

Please note that this is not a general "vs." question at all, but rather a question about this specific issue.

Comment: The only issue with Python 3.x is that it's not backwards-compatible with Python 2.x and people don't like to have to update their code and re-learn the language.

Comment: Adoption of Ruby 1.9.x seems to be speeding up, while Python 3.x is still not widely used. An good indicator of this is library support. For example, Django does not support Python 3.x while Rails runs on Ruby 1.9.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Python, most people are using the latest version of the 2 series. Python in general can be a nightmare as to mixing versions (at least, it used to be), but the solution is simply to deliver your software with the entire python environment it depends on.

Comment: Why aren't people switching to 3? Does this always happen with programming languages, it takes time for people to adopt the newer iterations?

Comment: 3 makes some largish changes to the language, so libraries will need to be ported to it (i.e. it's not backwards compatible with most of the codebase). For people who want to do real work, that means using 2. Which means that there isn't much pressure for anyone to port their library. Sometimes it just means that no-one really cares about the new language version, and it won't take off. Case in point: Perl 6.

Comment: Stuff is getting ported to Python 3, just not quickly. That's pretty much what you'd expect. But core libraries like numpy have made it.

Comment: Sure, but will anyone port any other libraries? Only time will tell.

Comment: Package Python with an application?  Very poor advice.  The last thing anyone needs is twenty separate Python installations.

Comment: @Glenn Maynard: The last time I tried to install any python-based application that didn't do that (admittedly some years ago), the differences in library versions and language features left those applications unable to run. Users won't notice or care that they have multiple python installations, but they will notice that your app doesn't even run.

Comment: @Marcin: Time says yes - http://dev.pocoo.org/~gbrandl/py3pkgs.png

Comment: @Thomas K: This is literally meaningless. Show me a graph of packages supported in 3 vs 2, weighted by active users (or any other sensible metric), then we'll talk.

Comment: I'd certainly notice if applications are 20-80 MB larger due to packaging a copy of Python.  Python isn't designed to be packaged as an "embedded" library (as Lua is, for example).  It's the package manager's job to handle versioning; current Debian provides 2.5, 2.6, 3.0 and 3.1.

Comment: Actually, it's your job to deliver working software if you want anyone to care about it.

Comment: @Marcin: You are misusing the word "literally". Of course, there are all sorts of caveats and questions, but the simple explanation is that support for Python 3 is gradually increasing. To look at it another way, here's the status of some notable packages: https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqIElKUDQl8tdC1lR29XZFlxZUxOU1VlZ1JRQ3ZRanc&hl=en_GB&authkey=CPLS9KMF .

Comment: @Thomas K: I think you are unfamiliar with the uses of the word "literally". Also, your spreadsheet looks to me like an argument against using python 3 for real work.

Comment: @Marcin: I didn't claim you could use it to do 'real work' (although that depends on the nature of your work). I claimed that Python 3 was not stuck in a situation where libraries will never bother to support it. Both the graph and the spreadsheet support this point.

Comment: @Thomas K: Not really. All they show is that some libraries claim some level of support for it.

Comment: @Marcin: Yes. And to make that claim, it's reasonable to suppose that people have spent time testing and fixing those libraries under Python 3. Which suggests it's not being completely ignored. You can ignore the evidence, but that's the way it points.

Comment: @Thomas K: No, the way the evidence points is that a couple of library writers have successfully forward ported their libraries, while the rest have either not bothered, or found it difficult to do successfully, and perhaps given up. This does not bode well for its future.

Comment: @Marcin: You have a strange sort of evidence. Many of the most widely used libraries have been ported or have a port in progress. The number of packages claiming support has more than doubled in the last year. Obviously there's loads of things not yet ported, but there's no evidence that it's losing momentum.

Comment: @Thomas K: I'm going by the data you have provided. Against, the number of packages claiming support is not especially interesting - the widely-used packages claiming support is what it is interesting.

Comment: @Marcin: The number of packages is indicative of general interest. And some of the most widely used packages (numpy, nose, cython, etc.) have already released Python 3 compatible versions. There are a couple holding out - Django and Twisted spring to mind, but the majority seem to be paying it some attention.

Comment: @Thomas K: I think it's telling that you can't pick three whose support is not reported to be qualified.

Comment: @Marcin: Do you mean my selection of numpy, nose and cython? I was deliberately referring to widely used libraries. Of course I picked ones which were on the spreadsheet, because when I look up a package's support, I update the spreadsheet. But this has descended into a stupid argument. Shall we agree to disagree?

Comment: @Thomas K: I'm referring to the fact that of the three you chose to mention, your spreadsheet lists the support as being qualified in the case of one of those three.

Comment: @Marcin: Oh, I see. It doesn't really alter the picture. Substitute virtualenv if you want.

Answer (score 3):

The issues aren't with Python 3.x, but the lack of a reasonable transition path from 2.x to 3.x causing most people to stay on 2.x.

It was a serious blunder, but an isolated one: aside from that, Python updates are very straightforward.

Comment: I disagree that making it backwards-compatible is a serious blunder. If you're familiar with the impetus, the issue is really a non-issue. It may be confusing at first, but not so much that a little bit of research will clear it up! :)

Comment: That should have been backwards-INcompatible, fwiw...

Comment: I'm not confused and I've done no small amount of "research".  It was a huge, language-fragmenting blunder that could have been avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Reminds me of the days I spent coding for Python 1.5.2 because 2.x had not had deep enough deployment to use any of the newer features -- it was a choice between customers and nice features.

It feels to me like Ruby users are more accustomed to having multiple versions installed simultaneously for the different levels of support in their software -- some require new 1.9 features, others won't work in the newer worlds. `rvm` makes it easier to manage multiple codebases, interpreters, and modules.

And it also feels to me like Python users rely more upon distribution-provided Python installs, and have less flexibility in running different versions. (Sure, it's not impossible or even hard to download and compile a new version in `/usr/local`, but how many do?)

Answer (score 1):

From Python's wiki on [choosing the right Python version](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3):

> Short version: Python 2.x is the
>   status quo, Python 3.x is the shiny
>   new thing.

Python 3.x is not 100% backwards-incompatible with 2.x. It's only in certain regards, but they happen to be fairly BIG regards.  The decision was made in Python 3 to attempt to fix some core architectural mistakes of the past, dating back to Python 1.x. Even having said that, almost all of the syntactical changes have been back-ported into Python 2.6.x and later.

This is by no means a comprehensive list, but here are a few key differences in Python 3:

- `print` is now a function and not a
  statement. This allows `print()` to
  be extended and accept arguments.
  You may access it in Python 2.6.x
  with `from __future__
  import print_function`. In Python 2.7 both methods are supported (statement: `print 'hi'`, function: `print('hi')`).
- Exception handling now requires the
  `except Foo as foo_err` syntax. (The
  former `except Foo, foo_err` syntax
  led to confusion in cases where you
  were catching multiple exceptions
  because of the comma-separated
  assignment to the variable.) Both formats are accepted by Python 2.6+.
- All classes inherit from `object` by
  default., there is no longer a need
  to explicitly subclass `object`
  when creating a new class. See
  (Python's [old-style vs. new-style
  classes](http://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass)).

One of the core problems with adoption of Python 3.x is because of these types of changes, which are major features. Many production environments still run on Python 2 and until we have wide-scale 3rd party library support in Python 3, adoption is going to be slow.

If you are just starting with Python, try the latest available versions. Currently that isversion 3.2. If you find that you don't get the library support you need, fallback to Python 2.7.2 and urge your library maintainers to port to Python 3!

Python 2.7 is going to be around for a long time and is the last major release of Python 2.x. This gives us plenty of time to get used to Python 3, because all of the major syntactical changes are already included by default.

Comment: Or it could just be that python 3 withers and dies. If I could bet on that, I would.

Comment: "This is by no means a comprehensive list..." What is the best way to obtain a comprehensive one?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Google? http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2010-June/1248324.html --- http://diveintopython3.org/porting-code-to-python-3-with-2to3.html --- http://docs.python.org/py3k/howto/pyporting.html

Answer (score 1):

If your OS is linux, you probably have Python installed (mine is Python version 2.6.5). Since  linux (Ubuntu in my case) actually uses Python, and Python 3.2 is not backwards compatible, I'd  better not remove version 2.6. I can however install Python 3.2 [alongside](http://pythonicway.blogspot.com/2011/02/install-python-32-on-linux-ubuntu.html) 2.6 and invoke it with 'python3'.

Ruby is generally not part of standard linux and the OS is not dependant on it, so Sysadmins and users are more inclined to upgrade, although ruby 1.9 is also not backward compatible. With rvm ([ruby version manager](https://rvm.io) ), you don't have to wait for the OS package manager, and you can switch versions easily.